# count based on store_A and all stores

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot, presto

I would like to count:

- all **count_products** for **store_A**
- the total **count_products** which includes all **store_id's** even store_A as **total_count_products**

Main_table

```
date         store_id  count_prroducts
2019-01-01   A         13
2019-01-01   B         34
2019-01-01   C         63
2019-01-01   D         10
```

Output_table

```
date          store_A_count_products    total_count_products
2019-01-0     13                        120
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start out by selecting the date column without any modifications.

For store_A_count_products, basically what you need to do is add up all of the count_products whenever the store_id is A. You can do this with a case statement:

```
   case when store_id = 'A' then count_products else 0 end
```

This is basically an IF/ELSE situation and will return a 0 for any row that doesn't have A in the store_id column.

If you wrap that up in a SUM(), you will add all the rows together.

For total_count_products, you just need to wrap a SUM() around count_products. This will add up all rows regardless of the status of any other column.

Finally, you need to group by the date column. The group by is a means to split the aggregated data across unaggregated columns.

The reason this works is because it gives you one row for each date, the summed total of products for Store A and the summed total of all products.

```
Select 
    date,
    Sum(case when store_id = 'A' then count_products else 0 end) as store_A_count_products,
    SUM(count_products) as total_count_products
From main_table
Group by date;
```

Comment: This seems to answer the question - however you should add an explanation on how the query works and why it solves the question. Code-only answer are discouraged on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Now *this* is an answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow!